# If a linear transformation is onto and one-to-one, is it always invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that if $T: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is invertible then it is also onto and 1-1.
But is it equivalent? In other words, are all linear transformations that are bijective considered invertible?

Comment: In general, one proves a function $f:A\to B$ is bijective $\iff$ is it invertible $\iff$ it is one-one and onto.

Comment: @merlin : The answer and above comment are correct.  Note that the bijective linear map $T$ can exist only if $m=n$.  Can you see why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By basic set theory, as alluded to in @Pedro's comment, a bijective linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ will have an inverse function $S : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. The interesting question from a linear algebra standpoint is

> Is the inverse $S$ also a linear transormation?

The answer to this question is **yes**.  Given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$ ax + by = a TSx + b TSy = T( aSx + bSy) $$
using  $TS = I_n$ for the first equality and linearity of $T$ for the second. Applying $S$ to both sides of the above equation and using $ST = I_m$ gives
$$ S(ax+by) = aSx + bSy$$
which says $S$ is linear.